# Can't get Array's count method to work with a block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Rails app that contains a `TeamSeason` model class. This class has a `has_one` association with a `Team` model class, and a `has_many` association to another `TeamSeason` called `opponents`. I'm now trying to write a method that passes in a `Team` and determines whether any of its opponents are associated with that `Team`. The method I wrote looks something like this:

```
def plays?(against_team)
  total = opponents.count {|opponent| opponent.team == against_team}
  return (total > 0)
end
```

The `count` method should count the number of array elements that yield a true value with the block I specified. However, it appears that it is always returning the full length of the array. It's as if the block I specified always yields a true value, no matter what.

I added various `puts` calls to try and figure out where my logic is going wrong. Here's my observations:

- When I add any `puts` calls inside the block next to the count method, I do not see any output for those statements. It appears that the contents of the block are never being executed
- When I insert an additional loop using the opponents array's `each` method and a block, I can print the value of my array objects and confirm they are evaluate as I expect. I can even `puts` the value of `opponent.team == against_team` and verify that the block I wrote evaluates to `false` some of the time, as it should.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I can't figure out what's wrong with your code. But you can implement the method without using count.  `opponents.where(team_id: against_team.id).exists?`

Comment: @jvnill: there is no `team_id` field in the team_seasons table, as it's a has_one relationship.  Rather, the teams table has a `team_season_id` field.

Comment: you are right. it should be `opponents.joins(:team).where(teams: { id:  against_team.id }).exists?` just like one of the answers but `teams` need to be plural.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`opponents` is not a standard ruby Array - it's an ActiveRecord association proxy and behaves differently for certain methods.  `count` will query the database for the number of opponents, and the block you are passing will not be evaluated.  A simpler way to do what you want is like so:

```
def plays?(against_team)
  opponents.joins(:team).where(teams: {id: against_team.id}).exists?
end
```

This will ask the database what you want, and avoid loading all opponents when you are only checking for a specific match.  Alternatively, you can load the entire opponents list and use `any?`:

```
def plays?(against_team)
  opponents.any?{|opponent| opponent.team == against_team.id}
end
```

Note that this will not only load all opponents, but it will load each opponent's team one at a time - resulting in an N+1 query (which leads to performance issues).  You can avoid this by eager loading the associated team using `includes()`:

```
opponents.includes(:team).any?{...}
```

Comment: as i said in my comment, i think your first code should use `teams` and not `team` or use `where('teams.id = ?', against_team.id)`

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification. I don't think I would have ever figured out that opponents wasn't a standard Ruby array here. I've just tried both of your variants and they both worked for me. Now that I know what is going on I can look deeper into how I will be using this to determine which approach will work best for me.

Comment: @PinnyM: I'm pretty sure it will cause some error.  just tried it on mysql and pg and on has_one and belongs_to association.

Comment: @jvnill: After trying this out, it seems you are correct - updated.

Answer (score 0):

The functionality which you are trying can be achieved using [`include?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-include-3F) method.

Try:

```
def plays?(against_team)
  opponents.collect(&:team).include?(against_team)
end
```

Comment: It seems to me that the include? method would only be applicable if I was directly testing the team object passed into my method for inclusion in the opponents array. However, that is not what I am trying to test. Instead, I am trying to find our if the team object being passed in is associated with any of the opponents via its team association. So I need something with a block expression to evaluate.

Comment: Using `collect` will result in N+1 queries, not great if you have lots of opponents...